# Can't get the path of the file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7

The code was working 100% but after shifting to iOS7 and XCode 5 I can't get the path of the file using NSFilemanager methods, the code can't find the path to timetableXML file and triggers -> else @"NO such a file exist",  Here is there code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    APUAppDelegate *appDelegate = (APUAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];


    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        NSLog(@"Beginning download");
        NSString *stringURL = @"http://webspace.apiit.edu.my/intake-timetable/download_timetable/timetableXML.zip";
        NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
        NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        NSLog(@"Got the data!");
        //Find a cache directory. You could consider using documenets dir instead (depends on the data you are fetching)
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *path = [paths  objectAtIndex:0];

        //Save the data
        NSLog(@"Saving");
        dataPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"timetableXML.zip"];
        dataPath = [dataPath stringByStandardizingPath];
        [urlData writeToFile:dataPath atomically:YES];

        /////////////////// TEST
        // Existence of the xml file

        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSString *pathToMyFile = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"timetableXML.zip"];
        if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:pathToMyFile]) {
            // file exists
            NSLog(@"YES a file exist with ZIP extension");
            NSLog(@"Unziped successfully!");
            path1 = pathToMyFile;
            [self unzipFile:path1];

        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"NO such a file exist");
        }         

    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When writing the file the path is created with this code:

```
dataPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"timetableXML.zip"];
dataPath = [dataPath stringByStandardizingPath];
```

but when testing the path is created with this code which is not the same:

```
NSString *pathToMyFile = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"timetableXML.zip"];
```

NSLog() both paths and try to find the problem.

Look and see if the file was written.
Note, there there was no check of the status of the `writeToFile:` method, add that error check.

Comment: Thank you for the solution Zaph. I did a check on both paths and they were the same. The write to file as well. what I am wondering is the time I use the back up on xcode 4 and iOS 6 everything works perfectly but on iOS 7 and xcode 5 This problem appear. yet I have to check more.